# Login permissible even though email address not verified

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I am using Django `rest-auth` and `allauth` for registration functionality. After a user registers, an email should be sent that a user is required to click on before they become an `active` user.

Currently, the user is marked as `is_active` in the `api_user` table as soon as they register (no email verification was required and I was also able to `login`).

I noticed the `verified` column in the `account_emailaddress` table is being updated correctly (set to `0` before email verification and `1` afterwards).

However this is does not seem to have any bearing on the `is_active` column in the `api_user` table.

These are my current `Django` settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.User'

ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION='mandatory'
```

Would anyone know what I might not be doing? Any explanations as to how this should work is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django-allauth` does not change the value of `is_active` based on the email verification.
According to their source code, they don't touch the is_active flag:
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py#L290